# Default Win32 project has constant number of memory leaks

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-leaks, gdi

### INTRODUCTION AND RELEVANT INFORMATION:

The original project I work on has small memory leaks, so I have decided to perform a small test so I can detect what could cause them.

I have created a Win32 project using Visual Studio wizard.
**I haven't added anything**, I have just left it as it was created with the wizard.
I have used the tool `GDIView` ( http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gdi_handles.html ) to see if there are any inherent `GDI leaks`.

### PROBLEM:

Each time I resize the window, this tool shows that there are +3 regions that my application leaks.

### MY EFFORTS TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM:

Since the project was made by the Visual Studio wizard, I have tried to create a simple project from scratch, but the same +3 regions appear.

Reading through some articles on *CodeProject* about regions I have stumbled upon some demo applications that demonstrate the usage of them.

When I turn on `GDIView` these applications also leak +3 regions.

All of this is verified when I turn on `Task Manager` to see if the small memory leak is really occurring-it does occur since the **memory slightly rises** and **stays constant afterwards** no matter how many times I resize the window.

I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition, but the problem was detected when empty project is created in regular Visual Studio 2008 as well.

I work on Windows XP, but the same effect happens on Windows 7.

### QUESTION:

Why is this happening and how to eliminate these small memory leaks?

Thank you.

Best regards.

Comment: 'stays constant afterwards' - no problem.  Probably not an actual leak.

Comment: have you tried building your app as a console subsystem exe, adding keyboard input at the end (after the event loop and window destruction), and checking GDI leak then? if the code is usual Microsoft non-standard `WinMain` then for this test you may have to tell the linker to use entry point `winMainCRTStartup`, or else change it to standard `main`.

Comment: @MartinJames But it "pokes" me right in the eye, and I wish to somehow remove it. Is it even possible to remove them, or are they inherent? No matter what I do, every well written Win32 application that I have found and tested so far has those 3 leaks. Thanks. Regards.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, No I haven't tried to build it that way but I am willing to try. Can you provide me some links to examples on how to do this, since I haven't done this before. Thanks. Regards.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff: sorry no link (I'd have to write it up as a blog article). but it's simple. First check if you have `WinMain`, `wWinMain`, `main` or `wmain` C++ main function. The corresponding entry points (specify to linker) are `winMainCRTStartup`, `wWinMainCRTStartup`, `mainCRTStartup` and `wmainCRTStartup`, if I remember correctly. The reason you have to deal with this is Microsoft non-standard unreasonable behavior (e.g. g++ has no such problem). So in linker options, set "subsystem" to "console" and "entry" to entry point function that calls your C++ main. Add kbd input. Build.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Main function is `_tWinMain` in the wizard generated project, and `WinMain` in the project I have wrote from "scratch". I am interested to fix the wizard generated project, so I ask you if I can start doing so by specifying the `winMainCRTStartup` in the linker options or for `_tWinMain` I need to specify something else? Thank you. Regards.

Comment: `tWinMain` is just a macro that expands to `WinMain` or `wWinMain` depending on the project's Unicode setting (no or yes). Or more specifically I think it's via the `_UNICODE` macro (runtime library macro), which the project setting affects, but it may be the `UNICODE` macro (Windows API macro)  --  it's some years since the 90's, and I haven't used that stuff since. By default in modern Visual Studio a project is Unicode, which then means that you have `wWinMain` (after macro expansion).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: OK, I have added "console" and `winMainCRTStartup` in the linker settings as you have suggested, and started the program. I didn't implement keyboard input yet. Console window appears that says "Press any key to continue...'. If I try to resize it, there are no memory leaks ( but I can not see my GUI, what happened to it? ).

Comment: I'm surprised that worked at all, it should bw `wWinMainCRTStartup`. Oh the ways of Microsoft are inscrutable. Anyway, at the "Press any key to continue" the program has already finished, and no memory leaks can be detected then -- so you need to stop it at the end e.g. with kbd input (which is the whole point).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Forgive me for this stupid question, but when you say kbd input, do you mean on `cin`, since this is now a console app ?

Comment: yes. . . . . . . . . for example.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: OK, I have added `int a; cin>>a;` at the very top of the program `winMainCRTStartup` and tried to resize the console window ( without entering the number `a` of course, since it would terminate the app ) and there were no memory leaks detected. If I put the above piece of code just before `return` statement the program ends with the message "Press any key to continue...'. Is this helpful to you? Regards.

Comment: Not sure what you're doing so I just tried this. First that setting entry point `wWinMainCRTStartup` didn't change anything, and it didn't. Then setting console subsystem: that worked, with GUI popping up on top of console window. Then adding `cin` input just before the `return (int) msg.wParam;`, that also worked nicely, namely that closing the GUI main window left the console window waiting for input. At this point you can check for resource/memory leaks. The main window has been closed. The question is, did it clean up nicely, as it should. With the program waiting for input, you can check.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Yes, the program performed proper cleanup-`GDIView` shows no memory leaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really something to worry about in terms of being an actual leak, as it probably isn't (i.e., a false-positive). The real problem is that this compromises your ability to diagnose your own memory leaks, as they could get "lost" with these false-positives.

> Why is this happening?

This kind of "leak" is quite common. I usually work with Qt + Linux (KDE) for GUI applications, and I see very similar "leaks" all the time. The problem is that within any GUI software, you will have at least these layers: your application, the GUI library, the OS "kernel" libraries, and the graphics drivers. In my experience, most of the reported "leaks" come from the graphics driver, presumably because that kind of low-level code requires a number of "hacks" that can be seen or detected as memory leaks by typical memory diagnostic tools like Valgrind (or whatever you are using). A similar argument can be made with OS kernel code, although in my experience there are much fewer "leaks" coming out of there (I'm think they might be putting a bit more effort into avoiding these "hacks"). In GUI libraries (Qt, Win32 API, etc.), there are often similar "leaks" too, for similar reasons. It is, of course, not excluded that there could be an actual leak in any of those layers, but you have to work under the presumption that there is none, and the fact that the memory consumption stabilizes after some time indicates that it probably is no real leak, at least, not any that could do damage (like runaway memory consumption) (btw, this behavior of memory consumption that increases and then stabilizes is perfectly normal, it has to do with heap-fragmentation that grows and eventually reaches equilibrium).

> how to eliminate these small memory leaks?

You can't really eliminate those leaks, especially if you really don't have anything to do with them (i.e., they are coming out of the GUI library stack, not from your application). The best you could do is report those diagnostics to whoever is in charge of support and maintenance of those libraries (e.g., Microsoft), but it is likely to be ignored or deemed to be a normal occurrence (not really a leak).

Now, to the real problem, if you want to diagnose your own potential memory leaks, then you will have to find a systematic way to circumvent or ignore the "leaks" coming from the GUI library stack. Here are a few typical solutions:

1. Check for leaks often and avoid doing the things (e.g., resizing) that increases the number of false-positives. Learn to "know your leaks" in the sense that by checking often, you will become familiar with the leaks that come out of the GUI library stack, and be able to ignore them or "subtract" them from the diagnostics and only see the real leaks.
2. Use filtering tools to filter the output of your memory diagnostic tool. Most tools to check for leaks will have filtering options to filter out (or to silence) warnings or errors coming out of certain libraries or functions. You can use those to silence the false leaks detected in these third-party libraries. But be careful not to filter too much (e.g., like filtering out all leaks coming from the CRT), you should remain conservative (you can even introduce deliberate memory leaks in your code to check that they don't get filtered out).
3. Modularize your application such that most of the important code (the heavy-lifting code) can be run in a simpler command-line program. In other words, make the GUI into a simple front-end (which is easy to make leak-free) that uses some heavy-lifting back-end code. You can transplant that back-end code into a much simpler command-line program, and thus, avoiding the GUI library stack completely and allowing you to check for memory leaks more effectively, without all the "pollution". This is the recommended solution for any serious project, and it also fosters good coding practices (unit-testing, modularized code, minimal inter-dependencies, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for your help. After performing the testings suggested by member ***Cheersandhth.-Alf*** I have seen that all of the `GDI leaks` dissapeared, which makes me think that your answer is true. I accept it and I sincerely thank you for such an educational answer. +1 from me. Best regards.